# Laravel Nova using nova's components and tools in application (outside of Nova)

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Wouldn't it be nice if we could also leverage **Nova components** (Index, Forms, Detail page, Cards or Tools from novapackages.com) in our external application too and not just be restricted to the nova admin panel?

1- Basically, we would just add the **scripts** and **css** for Nova in our `layout.blade.php`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('app.css', 'nova-assets') }}">
<script src="{{ mix('app.js', 'nova-assets') }}"></script>
```

2- Then we would be able to use the Nova components like for example, `resource-index`.

In our `blade.php` views

```
@section('content')
  My own custom content

  <resource-index :resource-name="'Post'"></resource-index>
@endcontent
```

Or in our `app.js`

```
 require('./bootstrap');
 window.Vue = require('vue');
 Vue.component('example-component', require('./nova/ResourceIndex.vue'));
 const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app'
 });
```

Does anyone know how we could leverage Nova's components and packages outside of the admin panel and in our main application?

Comment: I ended up creating my own Rapid Application Development Framework: https://kompo.io